# USB startup disk wont show in BIOS

Tags: boot, usb

I cannot install Ubuntu since the USB start up volume will not show in BIOS as a bootable device.

I have Tails on a different USB drive and that works just fine.

I have tried creating the startup volume using
1. Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator
2. Windows Linux Live Usb Creator
but I get same result.

I am running out of ideas, why is it possible to boot Tails from USB but not the Ubuntu?
BR,
Tobias

Comment: 1. Have you tried switching from UEFI to Legacy? 2. Have you checked whther your .iso image is not corrupted?

Comment: My hardware is from around 2006 so I figure UEFI is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the USB drive was not configured properly. Here is a method which is proven to work :

Use the **Disks** tool (`gnome-disk-utility`) to create the **Ubuntu installation media** properly.

Open **Disks** and select **Restore Disk Image** from the menu on the top right of the application.

Choose the **Ubuntu installation ISO file** and the **USB drive** to write it to and **start restoring**.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the Universal USB Installer on Windows to create my bootable USB volume, then it works for me. Thank you for your help.