# Dell Latitude E7250 Ubuntu 14.04 single boot problems

Tags: 14.04, boot, uefi

I have the following problem, and after a whole day reinstalling and searching the internet for solutions I decided to ask for advice here:

I wanted to install Ubuntu on my Laptop that ran pre-installed Windows 8. So I disabled secure boot and activated Legacy mode. After that I booted from my Multiboot USB and installed Ubuntu 14.04. However, when starting up again, booting from the internal HDD did not work. All I got to was a black screen showing:

> Selected boot device failed. Press any key to reboot the system.

Interestingly enough, when I boot from my Multiboot USB (YUMI) and continue with Boot from First HD (default) the system boots perfectly fine.

So I looked up this post: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI. This told me to activate UEFI and boot Ubuntu from there. After creating a Multiboot USB with EFI on it (I followed these instructions:http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2276498) the USB was found and I was able to boot a Live Version of Ubuntu 14.04.3 and install it (with efi-partition at sda1). However, when I boot from the HDD in UEFI-mode all I get is a black screen showing the following:

```
Press F1 key to retry boot.
Press F2 key to reboot into setup. 
Press F5 key to run onboard diagnostics.
```

Maybe one of you guys has an idea what goes wrong here? If I failed to give vital information let me know and I try to add it as best I can.

thx,
Buugy

Comment: I ran into similar problems, which were caused by badly created installation USB flash drive, solved with using Rufus win app. See me question [Ubuntu EFI boot problem - Dell Inspiron 13-7359](http://askubuntu.com/questions/742068/ubuntu-efi-boot-problem-dell-inspiron-13-7359)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issues following two steps mentioned somewhere else on this site:

First, make sure your issue isn't (just) a badly created installation USB flash drive, by scanning it for errors before your installation. For me personally, this was the first issue solved:

"Maybe the USB drive was not configured properly. Here is a method which is proven to work :

Use the Disks tool (gnome-disk-utility) to create the Ubuntu installation media properly.

Open Disks and select Restore Disk Image from the menu on the top right of the application.

Choose the Ubuntu installation ISO file and the USB drive to write it to and start restoring."

[USB startup disk wont show in BIOS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/700807/usb-startup-disk-wont-show-in-bios/700822#700822)

Then go in to the boot (F12) - and make sure you set to UEFI mode. As follows:

1.) In BIOS Setup: Disable the Compatibility Support Module (CSM; aka "legacy boot support" or similar terms) in your firmware.

2.) Change Boot Mode Settings to: UEFI: Secure Boot: OFF

[Ubuntu EFI boot problem - Dell Inspiron 13-7359](https://askubuntu.com/questions/742068/ubuntu-efi-boot-problem-dell-inspiron-13-7359)

Restart, and do the installation from USB installation flash drive. I hope this helped.